# How to Solve for X?

Tags: equation-solving

Have Mathematica solve sin(x) = 0 for x.  What I did was

h[x] := Sin[x];

and

Solve[h[x] == 0, x, Reals] // N

but its giving me a really weird answer .

What would be the proper way of finding all the roots.

Comment: `N[Reduce[Sin[x]==0,x]]` instantly shows `Element[C[1], Integers] && (x == 6.283185307179586*C[1] || x == 3.141592653589793 + 6.283185307179586*C[1])` and those are all the roots, all integer multiples of pi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
h[x_] := Sin[x]
```

Without converting the exact result to approximate numerical results

```
(sol = Solve[h[x] == 0, x, Reals]) // InputForm

(* {{x -> ConditionalExpression[
    2*Pi*C[1], Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
 {x -> ConditionalExpression[
    Pi + 2*Pi*C[1], Element[C[1], Integers]]}} *)
```

Verifying that the solutions satisfy the equation under the condition that [`C`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html)[1] is an integer (the condition specified in the [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html))

```
Assuming[Element[C[1], Integers], h[x] == 0 /. sol // Simplify]

(* {True, True} *)
```

The first solution is all even multiples of `Pi`. The second solution is all odd multiples of `Pi`. Consequently, the solution can be simplified to all integer multiples of `Pi`.

```
Assuming[Element[C[1], Integers], h[x] == 0 /. {x -> Pi*C[1]} // 
  Simplify]

(* True *)
```